# Passing an image pointer to a DLL function in python

Tags: python, pointers, dll, camera, ctypes

I have a camera that has its own DLL library for passing parameters to the camera, and taking images. I am trying to make calls with this DLL library through python. I need to make a pointer for the raw image data, and i'm not exactly sure how to do this. The DLL has a function name and takes those parameters as inputs:

StTrg_TakeRawSnapShot(hCamera, pbyteraw, dwBufferSize, dwNumberOfByteTrans, dwFrameNo, dwMilliseconds)

```
hCamera:
    This parameter sets the camera control handle that obtains by StTrg_Open. 

pbyteRaw:
    This parameter sets pointer of the raw image. 

dwBufferSize:
    This parameter sets the buffer size. 

pdwNumberOfByteTrans:
    This parameter sets the pointer that obtains the total number of the bytes of the image. 

pdwFrameNo:
    This parameter sets the pointer that obtains the frame number of the image that counts in the camera.
    This number can be use for the frame drop detection. 

dwMilliseconds:
    This parameter sets the timeout time (Unit is msecond).
```

exactly as stated from the documentation of the camera, pbyteraw is: "This parameter sets pointer of the raw image" and that's all the detail they provide.

how do i create this raw image pointer, and then read it to a 2D array that i can work with in python? The camera is black and white, so i am hoping to get a 2D array of values between 0 and 255.

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np

mydll = windll.LoadLibrary('StTrgApi.dll')
hCamera = mydll.StTrg_Open()


im_height = 1600
im_width = 1200
dwBufferSize = im_height * im_width

pbyteraw = (c_ubyte * dwBufferSize)()

dwNumberOfByteTrans = 0

dwFrameNo = 0

dwMilliseconds = 3000

mydll.StTrg_TakeRawSnapShot(hCamera, pbyteraw, dwBufferSize, 
dwNumberOfByteTrans, dwFrameNo, dwMilliseconds)


b_pbyte = bytearray(pbyteraw)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're working with numpy you can take advantage of the fact that [numpy arrays provide a ctypes interface](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html) that let you get a reference to the underlying data buffer, which would be suitable to pass to your DLL's function.  As long as you're happy keeping your data in a numpy array, try something like the following.

Instead of a ctypes array

```
pbyteraw = (c_ubyte * dwBufferSize)()
```

use a numpy array:

```
pbyteraw = np.zeros((im_height, im_width), dtype=np.uint16)
```

Then pass a reference to `pbyteraw` when calling `StTrg_TakeRawSnapShot`, as follows:

```python
mydll.StTrg_TakeRawSnapShot(hCamera,
                            pbyteraw.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_int16)),
                            dwBufferSize*2, dwNumberOfByteTrans,
                            dwFrameNo, dwMilliseconds)
```

It's not clear what the size and format of the underlying pixels in the buffer are supposed to be though.  For example, does the camera return 16-bit grayscale pixels?  Big or little endian?  You'll need to make sure that the numpy [dtype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html) agrees with the `data_as` ctype.

Answer (score 1):

With some minor changes, what you have should work.  Setting the `.argtypes` of the function will help catch errors, and if you make instances of the output parameters, you can pass them by reference:

```
dwNumberOfByteTrans = c_uint32()
dwFrameNo = c_uint32()
mydll.StTrg_TakeRawSnapShot.argtypes = c_void_p,POINTER(c_ubyte),c_uint32,POINTER(c_uint32),POINTER(c_uint32),c_uint32
mydll.StTrg_TakeRawSnapShot(hCamera, pbyteraw, dwBufferSize, byref(dwNumberOfByteTrans), byref(dwFrameNo), dwMilliseconds)
```

Your raw buffer is a 1D byte array.  You can do the math to access the right row/col, or use the ctypes interface numpy provides as @Ross mentioned to provide a more intuitive interface.

Comment: using this method, im able to retrieve the pbyteraw as a list height(1600) x width(1200) = (1920000) long of 0's and 1's. but this isnt enough data to make an image ... right?

thank you for your help