# camera image incorrectly formatted in ctypes pointer (python)

Tags: python, pointers, dll, camera, ctypes

I am using a DLL library to call functions to operate a camera in python, and i'm able to retrieve the image using ctypes but it's formatted incorrectly. The returned image is duplicated and half of it is blank. what do i need to do to fix this?

I have a labview program that correctly takes images from the camera, so that is how they are supposed to look like.

Correct image retrieved using Labview

[image: Image from Labview]

Image retrieved using Python:
[image: Image from Python]

the image is duplicated and also sideways in python.

python code:

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mydll = windll.LoadLibrary('StTrgApi.dll')
hCamera = mydll.StTrg_Open()
print(hCamera)

im_height = 1200
im_width = 1600

dwBufferSize = im_height * im_width

pbyteraw = np.zeros((im_height, im_width), dtype=np.uint16)

dwNumberOfByteTrans = 0
dwNumberOfByteTrans = (c_ubyte * dwNumberOfByteTrans)()

dwFrameNo = 0
dwFrameNo = (c_ubyte * dwFrameNo)()

dwMilliseconds = 3000
mydll.StTrg_TakeRawSnapShot(hCamera, 
pbyteraw.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_int16)), dwBufferSize*2, 
dwNumberOfByteTrans, dwFrameNo, dwMilliseconds)

print(pbyteraw)
plt.matshow(pbyteraw)
plt.show()
```

C++ code for taking the image:

```
DWORD dwBufferSize = 0;
    if(!StTrg_GetRawDataSize(hCamera, &dwBufferSize))
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Get Raw Data Size Failed.\n"));
        return(-1);
    }

    PBYTE pbyteRaw = new BYTE[dwBufferSize];
    if(NULL != pbyteRaw)
    {
        DWORD dwNumberOfByteTrans = 0;
        DWORD dwFrameNo = 0;
        DWORD dwMilliseconds = 3000;
        for(DWORD dwPos = 0; dwPos < 10; dwPos++)
        {

            if(StTrg_TakeRawSnapShot(hCamera, pbyteRaw, dwBufferSize, 
&dwNumberOfByteTrans, &dwFrameNo, dwMilliseconds))
        {
            TCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH];
            if(is2BytesMode)
            {
                _stprintf_s(szFileName, _countof(szFileName), TEXT("%s\\%u.tif"), szBitmapFilePath, dwFrameNo);
                StTrg_SaveImage(dwWidth, dwHeight, STCAM_PIXEL_FORMAT_16_MONO_OR_RAW, pbyteRaw, szFileName, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                _stprintf_s(szFileName, _countof(szFileName), TEXT("%s\\%u.bmp"), szBitmapFilePath, dwFrameNo);
                StTrg_SaveImage(dwWidth, dwHeight, STCAM_PIXEL_FORMAT_08_MONO_OR_RAW, pbyteRaw, szFileName, 0);
            }
            _tprintf(TEXT("Save Image:%s\n"), szFileName);
        }
        else
        {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Fail:StTrg_TakeRawSnapShot\n"));
            break;
        }
    }
    delete[] pbyteRaw;
}
```

Comment: Based on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48628322/235698) which indicated the raw buffer was a byte pointer, why are you using uint16 as the data type?  Also see my answer in your other question about passing the output parameters correctly.  You can check the output of `dwNumberOfByteTrans` to see if the buffer size you are sending and the amount you are receiving make sense.  It would help to show the exact prototype of the C function in the DLL, and even show working C code that calls the function correctly.

Comment: I dont know why, im not sure what to use. When i use uint8, python crashes while calling the take snapshot function. When I use uint32, it will work, but the displayed image is even smaller (less resolution and more blank space). I've also tried ubyte as the data type, and i get a memory error:

OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x074B5000

Comment: I dont know why, im not sure what to use. When i use uint8, python crashes while calling the take snapshot function. When I use uint32, it will work, but the displayed image is even smaller (less resolution and more blank space). I've also tried ubyte as the data type, and i get a memory error:

OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x074B5000

i added the cpp code, and adding the .argtypes didnt seem to make a difference. 

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Based on your C code, something like this should work, but it is untested since I don't have your camera library.  If you are using 32-bit Python, make sure the library calls are `__stdcall` to use `WinDLL`, else use `CDLL`.  64-bit Python it doesn't matter.  Defining the argument types and return type helps catch errors.  For output parameters, create instances of the correct ctype, then pass `byref()`.  The way you were currently doing the output parameters was likely the cause of your crash.  Setting argtypes would have detected that the values weren't pointers to DWORDs.

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes as w

mydll = WinDLL('StTrgApi')

mydll.StTrg_Open.argtypes = None
mydll.StTrg_Open.restype = w.HANDLE

mydll.StTrg_GetRawDataSize.argtypes = w.HANDLE,w.PDWORD
mydll.StTrg_GetRawDataSize.restype = None

mydll.StTrg_TakeRawSnapShot.argtypes = w.HANDLE,w.PBYTE,w.DWORD,w.PDWORD,w.PDWORD,w.DWORD
mydll.StTrg_TakeRawSnapShot.restype = None

hCamera = mydll.StTrg_Open()
print(hCamera)

dwBufferSize = w.DWORD()
mydll.StTrg_GetRawDataSize(hCamera,byref(dwBufferSize))

pbyteraw = (w.BYTE * dwbufferSize)()
dwNumberOfByteTrans = w.DWORD() # output parameters.  Pass byref()
dwFrameNo = w.DWORD()           # output parameters.  Pass byref()
dwMilliseconds = 3000

mydll.StTrg_TakeRawSnapShot(hCamera,
                            pbyteraw,
                            dwbufferSize,
                            byref(dwNumberOfByteTrans),
                            byref(dwFrameNo),
                            dwMilliseconds)
```

Comment: I solved the problem, I had to use the numpy array of uint8 data type and pass this as the pbyteraw argument as a pointer and it worked. using uint16 would display two images (like in the original image i posted), and uint32 would display four duplicate images with the rest of the image below blank. i really dont understand how changing  the data type can result in duplicated images. thank you for your help

Comment: @zonzon510 It's not duplicating the image.  With 16-bit data you are allocating a buffer twice as big, and a row has twice as many bytes, so one "row" contains two rows of real data.  That's also why the last half of your image was blank...only the first half was filled with the byte data.